# Using the MockDataProvider of JOOQ, how do I set the lastId() that gets returned?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jooq

*Note: I am not using the code generator of Jooq*

In the DAO unit test, the DAO is tested to ensure that after a object has been inserted that the DAO sets the Id as returned by the last_insert_id() from the database. No actual database is contacted since I'm using the MockConnection and MockDataProvider of JOOQ.

When the following is executed by the DAO:

```
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
//insert
//get id
BigInteger id = ctx.lastId();
```

JOOQ executes the following query:

```
select last_insert_id() from dual;
```

In my MockDataProvider I check when this query is executed and return a result accordingly:

```
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.dual;

//other code

@Override
public MockResult[] execute(MockExecuteContext ctx) throws SQLException {
   Field<BigInteger> id = DSL.field("", BigInteger.class);
   Record record = dual().newRecord();
   record.setValue(id, BigInteger.valueOf(1234567));
   return new MockResult[] { new MockResult(record) };             
}
```

When the above MockResult is returned, I get the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field () is not contained in Row ()
```

What is the correct way to populate the MockResult for the last_insert_id() query ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a working implementation for your `MockDataProvider` for `DSLContext.lastID()`:

```
BigInteger expected = BigInteger.valueOf(1234567);
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(new MockConnection(c -> {
    Field<BigInteger> id = DSL.field("last_insert_id()", BigInteger.class);
    Record record = DSL.using(MYSQL).newRecord(id);
    record.setValue(id, expected);
    return new MockResult[] { new MockResult(record) };
}), SQLDialect.MYSQL);

assertEquals(expected, ctx.lastID());
```

There are essentially two things that went wrong in your approach:

#### The field name

The field name of the field you're selecting is really called `last_insert_id()` (at least in jOOQ 3.5.3), thus you also have to name your mock field this way:

```
    Field<BigInteger> id = DSL.field("last_insert_id()", BigInteger.class);
```

#### The Record

You have to create a record that already contains your field in it. The `dual()` table contains a different field. The fact that jOOQ generates a `from dual` query is irrelevant to the fact that you have to produce a `Record` that contains a `last_insert_id()` field:

```
    Record record = DSL.using(MYSQL).newRecord(id);
```

#### Warning

Of course, you're making a strong assumption about jOOQ's implementation as it is in 3.5.3. There is no guarantee that the exact query generated by `DSLContext.lastID()` will always be

```
select last_insert_id() from dual
```

Comment: Most awesome part of jOOQ is that if you ask a reasonable question on SO the jOOQ creator will always give you an answer ;)

Comment: You may have asked the question. But dozens of others will google it. Having a good answer matters to a lot of people