# jOOQ db mock record.store() add fake id to record

Tags: java, mysql, unit-testing, mocking, jooq

Consider the following excerpt from a DAO method:

```
  newRecord = db.newRecord(ACCOUNT);
  newRecord.setName(newAccountName);
  newRecord.store();
```

In production, this successfully insert a new record, and also sets the `id` of the `newRecord` object to the actual `id of the inserted record.

Now consider the following excerpt from a unit test for this method:

```
Connection connection = new MockConnection(c -> {
  AccountRecord record = DSL.using(SQLDialect.MYSQL).newRecord(ACCOUNT);
  record.setId(ULong.valueOf(5));
  record.setName("bananas");
  return new MockResult[] { new MockResult(record) };
});
DSLContext mockContext = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.MYSQL);

JSONObject actualResult = testDAO.createNewAccount("bananas");
```

It turns out, the above test fails to set the `id` on the `newRecord` when `.store()` is called.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that for now, I've ditched the `.store()` method in my DAOs, in favor of `db.insertInto()` followed by checking `db.lastID()`. It's a little more complex, in that the MockConnection needs to check which of two statements it's responding to, and send back a result for `last_insert_id()` in the latter. See [Using the MockDataProvider of JOOQ, how do I set the lastId() that gets returned?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081837/using-the-mockdataprovider-of-jooq-how-do-i-set-the-lastid-that-gets-returned) for more details on that implementation during testing.

Comment: Pending issue on GitHub: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6576